# Porting Python 2 code that uses _multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy

I'm currently porting some Python 2 code that was being run with pypy over to python 3. I'm a bit stuck with dealing with some code that uses `_multiprocessing` as the documentation is hard to find for this.

```
from _multiprocessing import address_of_buffer
#example usage
def buffer_info(self):
    return address_of_buffer(self._mmap)[0], self._size
```

When I attempt to use this code into Python3.4 I get a problem with the import:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'address_of_buffer'
```

After having a quick look at the Python 3 docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html I'm not seeing a direct replacement for this. What is the best way to port this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ctypes:

```
def address_of_buffer(buf):
    return ctypes.addressof(ctypes.c_char.from_buffer(buf))
```

Comment: I think that this does what I need so I upvoted, I haven't quite got the code that this uses passing all tests just yet, will mark as accepted when all the tests pass.